# Error: cannot convert 'std::string (aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' in assignment

Tags: c++

I have a problem - I want to store values from standard input line to an int but am unsure how to convert to an int:

```
string line;
int value;
getline(cin,line);
istringstream ss(line);
while (ss>>line) {
    if (ss.eof()==false) {
        // stores non ints in strings
    }
    else {
        value=line; //ERROR
    }
}
```

I have tried to convert this using standard documentation material but I am going nowhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simply doing `while(cin >> value)` will generally be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stoi`:

```
value=std::stoi(line);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and I'm getting error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'. I have included the right libraries eg. std::stoi so is this not a library problem?

Comment: @theBookeyMan Did you include <string>, are you using c++11?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your `istringstream` to try loading a value into an int while checking for `ss.fail()`.

```
ss >> temp; // where temp is an int
if(ss.fail())
{
// handle the error because the value wasn't an int
}
else
{
// process your int
}
```

This, naturally, could be modified a bit based on your needs.

Comment: There may be a cleaner way to do this though...